# Can't delete char array using cpp

Tags: c++, bittorrent

I create a char array in the start of the function, in the wnd I want it to be deleted.

This is my code so far:

```
void GetPiece(int size)
{
    //std::cout << "Downloading File Index: " + currFileIndex <<  " More: " + pieceSize - size;
    char * newBuffer = new char[size];
    bitRequest->RecvBySize(newBuffer, size - 4, 5);
    newBuffer += 8;
    File file("work_torrent.mp3");
    file.WriteToFile(newBuffer, size - 4);
    file.Close();

    pieceSize -= size -4;
    std::cout << "Downloading File Index: " << currFileIndex << " More: " << pieceSize << std::endl;

    if (pieceSize <= 0)
    {
        currFileIndex++;
        pieceSize = pieces.at(currFileIndex).fileSize;
    }

    offset += size - 4;

    if (pieceSize > 16384)
    {
        if (1048576 - offset < 16384)
        {
            requestSize = 1048576 - offset;
            if (requestSize == 0)
            {
                offset = 0;
                currPieceIndex++;
                if (pieceSize > 16384)
                {
                    requestSize = 16384;
                }
                else {
                    requestSize = pieceSize;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            requestSize = 16384;
        }

    }
    else {
        requestSize = pieceSize;
    }



    bitRequest->RequestPiece(currPieceIndex, offset, requestSize);

    delete[] newBuffer; // Try to delete it


}
```

When it reaches to the line which delete the char array it gives an error:

[image]

When I am not deleting this char array the code throws a allocation error after some calls to the function.

**Edit:**

When I didn't increament the newBuffer by 8 the given error is:
[image]

Someone know why it's happend?

Comment: You incremented `newBuffer` by `8`. How should that work out?

Comment: Why do manual memory management in the first place? Why not use an `std::vector<char>`?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer :) I edited my question, pleese look at it.